# Hadoop- How can I fix the errors of compilation

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I downloaded a program contains 8 Java classes and 2 files.sh ( [compile.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItROF.png) and [execute.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc6u9.png) ) and one jar file. I edit the `Jars locations` in `compile.sh` file, but when I compile it I got a `Java errors` like:

**graphMining.java:19: error: cannot find symbol**

**import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner**

**symbol:   class ToolRunner**

**location: package org.apache.hadoop.util**

**graphMining.java:22: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io.compress does not exist**

**import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool;**

**graphMining.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
            public void reduce(Text symbol, Iterator values, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter)**

I fixed `JAVA_HOME` path in `hadoop-env.sh` and when I write `echo $JAVA_HOME` it works. *What should I do please?*

Comment: Not really enough information here to fix your problem, unless you show us `compile.sh` and what you changed in it.

Comment: Did it work before you changed `compile.sh`?

Comment: could you copy/past your code in there instead of having it like images? This would be way quickest for everybody ;)

Comment: @MatthewCliatt the `compile.sh` didn't works before because the developper used hadoop 0.20 but I use the cloudera 5.4 so I should edit the jars path 
@J.Chomel : this is the `compile.sh before edit`:

`rm dmtl.jar `

`javac -classpath ../hadoop-core-0.20.203.0.jar:../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:commons-codec-1.2.jar 
MRStats.java MR_CannonicalCode.java MR_Pattern.java Util_functions.java MR_Serialize.java 
MyInputFormat.java mapperReader.java graphMining.java `

`jar -cvf dmtl.jar *.class `
`rm *.class `